# Show image in JTextPane

Tags: image, swing, jtextpane

I know we can set html as `JTextPane` content type and then use `img` tag to display image but here I have image data in bytes and `img` do not accept bytes it just wants url. So how can I show that image in JTextPane? Any other solution for this situation?

I have tried storing image temporary at Temp directory and then give it's url in `img` but didn't get any success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way is to use [JEditorPane](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html) instead of JTextPane. There you would have to set [HTMLEditorKit](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/HTMLEditorKit.html). After that, following html should work (only with absolute paths).

```
<html><img src="file:\\c:\images\example.gif" width=200 height=200></img>
```

More information is at http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html

Comment: Saving image in temp folder and then giving path like this works. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @eugener. Instead of? [JTextPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextPane.html) is a subclass of JEditorPane. Also, if you [set the base of the HTMLDocument](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/HTMLDocument.html#setBase(java.net.URL)) you can use relative URLs.